# Why can't we call a mocked method on a class variable?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito

I've been learning Scala recently, and right now, I am trying to do some learning tests with Mockito, but I've been facing something quite odd.

**FooService.scala**

```
class FooService extends Serializable {

  val service: FooDaoTrait = FooDao
  val fooResult = service.getAllTheFoosFromDatabase     

  def putTheFoosInASet(): Set[String] = {
    fooResult.split(",").toSet
  }
}
```

**FooServiceTest.scala**

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class FooServiceTest extends FunSuite with MockitoSugar {

  val m = mock[FooDaoTrait]
  when(m.getAllTheFoosFromDatabase).thenReturn("Hi, my name is foo")

  val instance = new FooService{ override val service = m }

  test("Let's get da Foos") {
    assert(instance.putTheFoosInASet().size === 3) // 3 is a random Value
  }
}
```

So here, when i run the test, Scala IDE is throwing the one and only `java.lang.NullPointerException` on my class variable `fooResult`.

But Somehow, when i move `FooResult` inside the `putTheFoosInASet()`:

```
  def putTheFoosInASet(): Set[String] = {
    val fooResult = service.getAlltheFoosFromDatabase  
    fooResult.split(",").toSet
  }
```

No exception is thrown and everything works well... 
Why does the previous pattern is throwing me an exception? I am not really sure what can cause this error and calling `fooResult` on different methods is not really clean imo.

Any opinion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer:

This is not a problem with mockito. To fix this, use `lazy`:

```
class FooService extends Serializable {
  val service: FooDaoTrait = FooDao
  lazy val fooResult = service.getAllTheFoosFromDatabase    

// ...
```

### Long answer:

Let's forget about Mockito and Mocks. We can still reproduce the problem:

```
val testFooDao = new FooDaoTrait {
  def getAllTheFoosFromDatabase() = "Hi, my name is foo"
}
val instance = new FooService { 
  override val service = testFooDao 
}
// ----> java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Ok, so what's happening? Adding some prints can help us understand:

```
class FooService extends Serializable {
  val service: FooDaoTrait = new FooDao("aa")
  println(s"Original FooService service is $service")
  val fooResult = service.getAllTheFoosFromDatabase
}

val testFooDao = new FooDaoTrait {
  def getAllTheFoosFromDatabase() = "Hi, my name is foo"
}
val instance = new FooService { 
  override val service = testFooDao 
  println(s"New FooService service is $service")
}
```

This prints

```
// Original FooService service is null 
// NullPointerException ...
```

That's why we got the `NullPointerException`. Since `service` is null `service.getAllTheFoosFromDatabase` give us this exception.

Why did this happened?

In scala, initialization of strict vals (not lazy) is done in the following order:

1. Superclasses are fully initialized before subclasses.
2. Otherwise, in declaration order.

But when val is overridden, it is not initialized more than once. Although your `service` attribute is defined twice, this overridden val will appear to be null during the construction of the superclass (FooService).

You can find more info [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html)

## EXTRA

Judging your code by your example (don't know if I can ;P), I have two suggestions, hope you don't mind:

First, I think `FooService.service` would be better and more elegant if you passed it as class constructor parameter. Specially if you intend to mock the service, this is how people usually do it (not only in scala, but in other languages):

```
class FooService(service: FooDaoTrait) {
// ...
```

Second, `fooResult` seems to me more like a query to the database, so it makes more sense for it to be a function (since it should change every time you query it)

```
class FooService extends Serializable {
  val service: FooDaoTrait = new FooDao("aa")
  def fooResult = service.getAllTheFoosFromDatabase
// ...
```

Notice that if you took any of this suggestions (or both) you wouldn't face this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry you reached such an obscure corner case of the language. I myself never crossed into this before answering your question :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Since you ask about **FooService.service** I saw it from [this article](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/2014/06/29/simple-dependency-injection-scala/) and i liked that pattern because if I call the service on another class, I don't have create a new **FooDaoTrait**

Comment: As he says, his article is like blasphemy! (LOL). But hey, I'm not radical. The thing from your code that is different from his is the `fooResult` attribute. As I said, `fooResult` seems to me more like a query and thus like a method (Its outputs can change everytime you call it). You would probably be fine with just declaring and using it `fooResult` as class method, not a class attribute.